# What to set Spark Master address to when deploying on Kubernetes Spark Operator?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, spark-operator

The official [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#cluster-mode) only has information on the `spark-submit` method for deploying code to a spark cluster. It mentions we must prefix the address from kubernetes api server with `k8s://`. What should we do when deploying through [Spark Operator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator)?

For instance if I have a basic pyspark application that starts up like this how do I set the master:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

sc = SparkContext("local", "Big data App")
spark = SQLContext(sc)
spark_conf = SparkConf().setMaster('local').setAppName('app_name')
```

Here I have `local`, where if I was running on a non-k8's cluster I would mention the master address with `spark://` prefix or `yarn`. Must I also use the `k8s://` prefix if deploying through the Spark Operator?
If not what should be used for master parameter?

Answer (score 3):

It's better not to use `setMaster` in the code, but instead specify it when running the code via spark-submit, something like this (see [documentation for details](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#submitting-applications-to-kubernetes)):

```sh
./bin/spark-submit \
    --master k8s://https://<k8s-apiserver-host>:<k8s-apiserver-port> \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    your_script.py
```

I haven't used Spark operator, but it should set master automatically, as I understand from the documentation.

you also need to get convert this code:

```py
sc = SparkContext("local", "Big data App")
spark = SQLContext(sc)
spark_conf = SparkConf().setMaster('local').setAppName('app_name')
```

to more modern (see [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html#starting-point-sparksession)):

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

as `SQLContext` is deprecated.

P.S. I recommend to get through first chapters of Learning Spark, 2ed that is [freely available from the Databricks site](https://databricks.com/p/ebook/learning-spark-from-oreilly).